# TCP_NODELAY for All current sockets in linux

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, socket

i want lowest latency network with tcp_nodelay., in windows OS we can easily enable TCP_NODELAY through registry of windows. i searched on the red hat website and another website but up to now, my problem hasn't been resolved. so i request you humbly to help me and tell me , how can i Enable Tcp_nodelay for all current sockets in linux network? thank you for helping